# Java ZipInputStream breaks in a thread, but not in main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, zip

I'm unable to wrap my head around this. The following code works perfectly:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //new Thread(() -> {

        try {
            Path zipFile = Paths.get("C:\\path\\to\\zipfile.zip");
            Path outDir = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("C:\\path\\to\\outDir"));

            try (ZipInputStream inputStream = new ZipInputStream(Files.newInputStream(zipFile))) {


                ZipEntry entry;
                while ((entry = inputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                    Path outPath = outDir.resolve(entry.getName());
                    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                        if (!Files.exists(outPath)) {
                            Files.createDirectory(outPath);
                        }
                    } else {
                        try (OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(outPath)) {
                            inputStream.transferTo(outputStream);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(entry.getName());
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    //}).start();

}
```

However, uncommenting the thread code causes the program to hang at the exact same file every time:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Thread(() -> {

        try {
            Path zipFile = Paths.get("C:\\path\\to\\zipfile.zip");
            Path outDir = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("C:\\path\\to\\outDir"));

            try (ZipInputStream inputStream = new ZipInputStream(Files.newInputStream(zipFile))) {


                ZipEntry entry;
                while ((entry = inputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                    Path outPath = outDir.resolve(entry.getName());
                    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                        if (!Files.exists(outPath)) {
                            Files.createDirectory(outPath);
                        }
                    } else {
                        try (OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(outPath)) {
                            inputStream.transferTo(outputStream);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(entry.getName());
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }).start();

}
```

If I try to debug the program, it works fine, only when running in non-debug mode, within a thread does this occur. Furthermore, the zip extracts without issue using Windows Explorer and 7-Zip. I'm approaching hair-pull-out levels on this, any help is greatly appreciated.

For reference, the zip file I'm using for testing (I'm working on a mod launcher for 7 Days to Die) can be found here: https://github.com/KhaineGB/DarknessFallsBBM45/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

Comment: I've tried from within the IDE, I've tried from the command line at it all seems to work just fine for me.  Could be a permissions issue with Windows.  I would recommending making sure that the output location is empty before you start extracting

Comment: The output dir doesn't exist before the script runs. As for permissions, I don't see what that would change between running in the main thread vs a second thread. It all runs the exactly the same (same input file, same clean/empty output dir), the only difference is the extra thread.

Comment: Where exactly does it hang? If you get a thread dump (e.g. with jstack), what is the thread doing?

Comment: What happens if you `join()` the thread?  Thread t = new Thread(...); t.start(); t.join();  Also, does anything at all happen? Does the output folder get created?

Comment: I haven't been able to get a thread dump, the entire jvm seems to hang. Windows Task Manager shows the process as "suspended", and I have to kill it and the IntelliJ process that spawned it to get it to actually die. The process gets about 12% of the way through extracting the Zip and then just... stops. No error, I can't pause the JVM and see what's going on, nothing. I've tried with AdoptJDK and OpenJDK and both do the same thing.